# how convert keyboard type in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying  When the user click on a UiTextfield i need to change the keyboard view to the alpha view automatically, is this possible? when user enter in the textfield then he or she should not be alb to enter numeric value in text field in iphone

how can i do this please help me friend

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UITextField** 's protocol `UITextInputTraits` has the property to change the keyboard type.

```
@property(nonatomic) UIKeyboardType keyboardType

myTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable;
```

Try with the possible values of [UIKeyboardType](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIKeyboardType) .

I'm not sure about whether you could bring the alpha effect on the existing keyboard view or not
But `UITextField` provide a property `inputView` to add own input view (custom keyboard).

```
@property (readwrite, retain) UIView *inputView;
```

Comment: i did't get u could u give more detail

Comment: @Rocky : I mean, you have choice of displaying different -2 keyboard type in your application, But I am not sure about showing keyboard with alpha effect. and i also mentioned the alternative using "inputView" . let me if you have still doubt.

Comment: sorry it's my mistake i want only alphabet in textfield not numeric in textfield

Comment: @Rocky :np , try with different keyboard type, I have already provided the link in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`UITextField` conforms to `UITextInputTraits` protocol which  has `keyboardType` property which can be set.

Example:

```
myField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
```