# How to limit iOS keyboard to numeric input

Tags: ios, keyboard, numeric

The question pretty much says it all. Is there any way to have the iOS/iPhone keyboard default to numeric input?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how convert keyboard type in iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200941/how-convert-keyboard-type-in-iphone)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Set the `keyboardType` property of the `UITextField` to `UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad`.

#### Swift 3

`yourUITextField.keyboardType = .decimalPad`

Comment: by doing this you get a keyboard that does not have a "return" or "ok"  button, so the solution is more complex, I used  UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation which gives the normal keyboard but shifted to the number input, it includes a return key.

Comment: @godzilla : If you care for return key, you can use [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) which will add Done button on the top of keyboard and this library help you for other many issues...

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C:

Default to Numbers (but include - and . if you need to allow decimal or negative numbers):

```
myTextField1.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
```

Default to Numbers (#s only for integer values)

```
myTextField1.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
```